# Postgresql Suddenly Stopped Logging

Tags: postgresql-9.2, opensuse

My system:

- Opensuse 13.1
- Postgresql 9.2
- Pgadmin3

I turned the stderr logging on.
It has been working for months now without any problems so far.
My logging file size is capped at 10MB and on average I generate about 2 - 3 10MB file size (I believe its not too much transactions in a day). Then on November 22nd, the logs just stopped for that day and on the 23rd and until today, it has been logging with no problem.

Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: Have you got any solution? facing similar issue